# Can I have multiple ListViews on the same screen?

Tags: android-listview

I'm creating an Android app for a large screen device.  From the User's perspective, I'd like to have at least two, maybe three, lists of objects that they can scroll through.

I was originally thinking of using ListView, but after reading the documentation, it seems ListView is better suited for occupying the entire screen, or activity

Can I have multiple ListViews on the same screen?  If not, what would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Nevermind, I have figured out how to do this.  It was fairly straightforward.

Comment: Share what you did found(as an answer) my friend it might help others or you could get better options.

Comment: I added the second ListView in the same exact way as I added the first, but changed the ID tag.